# How to change the shape of legend entry?

Tags: c#, charts

I'm developing a chart in a C# WebForm application. In the legend part, I cannot change the indicator/image/shape to a dash. (It can be done easily using excel. How do I do that?

What I want is:

```
 - - - - Income Average (Imagine is dashed image)
 ------- Income (Imagine is a solid line)
```

The closest I can make is:

```
LegendItem item1 = new LegendItem();
item1.Color = Color.Black;
item1.Name = "Income Average";
item1.BackHatchStyle = ChartHatchStyle.DarkVertical;

// Adding it into chart legend
chart1.Legends[0].CustomItems.Add(item1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `item1.ImageStyle = LegendImageStyle.Line` to create a solid line.
[More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.legendimagestyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

However there is no "dash" style as far as I know, but it is possible to use an image as a symbol. So you could try and make a small image of a dashed line and [read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.legenditem.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I hope it helps.